# How do I create a named function expressions in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

How do I create a named function expressions in CoffeeScript like the examples below?

```
var a = function b (param1) {}
```

or

```
return function link (scope) {}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  CoffeeScript doesn't allow you to, and its typically unnecessary (just assign the function to a variable).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function declaration in CoffeeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548750/function-declaration-in-coffeescript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coffeescript doesn't support the latter (named functions), but the former can be achieved with

```
a = (param1) ->
    console.log param1
```

Comment: That's an anonymous function expression. I wanted a named function but you say coffeescript doesn't support them. that's a bit rubbish.

Comment: Here is a (very) old thread, but it explains the stance they took and why they still do not allow named function expressions in coffeescript: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/15

Answer (score 5):

I may be a bit late to the party, but I just realised that you actually create named functions when using the `class` keyword.

Example:

```
class myFunction
  # The functions actual code is wrapped in the constructor method
  constructor: ->
    console.log 'something'

console.log myFunction # -> function AppComponent() { ... }
myFunction() # -> 'something'
```