# Pass a list of named functions into function in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, casperjs

In the API Documentation there is a snippet:

```
casper.waitFor(function check() {
    return this.evaluate(function() {
        return document.querySelectorAll('ul.your-list li').length > 2;
    });
}, function then() {
    this.captureSelector('yoursitelist.png', 'ul.your-list');
}, function timeout() {
    this.echo("I can't haz my screenshot.").exit();
});
```

I need this, but in a coffeescript project. I tried to rewrite it into coffeescript but it didn’t work. Even if i let [js2coffe](http://js2coffee.org/) do the job, i get some invalid coffeescript from valid javascript:

[image]

i dont know how to pass a list of named functions into another function correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript doesn't really support named functions like that, see:

- [How do I create a named function expressions in CoffeeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22221270/479863)
- [Function declaration in CoffeeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6548750/479863)

That specific example doesn't need them anyway, it looks like they're just there for documentation purposes so you could write:

```
check    = -> @evaluate(-> document.querySelectorAll('ul.your-list li').length > 2)
and_then = -> @captureSelector('yoursitelist.png', 'ul.your-list')
timeout  = -> @echo("I can't haz my screenshot.").exit()
casper.waitFor(check, and_then, timeout)
```

in CoffeeScript to get the same effect.

Comment: They're there primarily for documentation purposes, but they will be printed in some cases when there is an error or when verbose logging is enabled.

Comment: @ArtjomB. But like I said, CoffeeScript doesn't support them so you're out of luck unless you want to do unnatural things with backticks. If you have a problem with this then CoffeeScript isn't the right language for you.

Comment: @muistooshort sometimes you don’t choose coffeescript yourself. e.g. when you fix a bug in an existing coffeescript-app ;) but thats not the question here anyways.. your answer is correct. Thank you!!