# Cannot declare named function in coffee-script

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

If I want to get a function's name by `constructor.name`.

For example, in js we can do something like this:

```
var Foo = function Foo() {
    // I need other public methods can also access this private property.
    var non_static_private_member = 10;

    this.a_public_method = function() {
        non_static_private_member = 1;
    }

    console.log(non_static_private_member++);
}
var a = new Foo(); // output >> "10"
var b = new Foo(); // output >> "10"

console.log(a.constructor.name); // output >> "Foo"
```

But in coffee the `b = new Foo` can't output `10`, it output `11`:

```
class Foo
   non_static_private_member = 10
   constructor: ->
       console.log(non_static_private_member++)

a = new Foo  # output >> "10"
b = new Foo  # output >> "11"
console.log a.constructor.name # output >> "Foo"
```

But if I declare coffee like this, the output of `a.constructor.name` is wrong:

```
Foo = ->
   non_static_private_member = 10
   console.log(non_static_private_member++)

a = new Foo  # output >> "10"
b = new Foo  # output >> "10"
console.log a.constructor.name # output >> ""
```

#### How do you translate the js code above to coffee?

Comment: a) `.name` is non-standard, you shouldn't use it anyway. b) why don't you use `class` syntax for constructors (you still, for some reason, invoke `Foo` with `new`)?

Comment: @Bergi See comment in the second line of javascript.

Comment: Which one, the "*I need other private methods*"? How would that prevent you from using `class` syntax?

Comment: @Bergi I update my question, please see it. See the a_public_method part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoffeeScript will only generate named functions when used with `class` syntax.
Basically, your first snippet will translate into

```
var Foo;
Foo = (function() {
    var non_static_private_member;
    non_static_private_member = 10;
    function Foo() {
        console.log(non_static_private_member++);
    }
return Foo;
})();
```

while second will become

```
var Foo;
Foo = function() {
    var non_static_private_member;
    non_static_private_member = 10;
    return console.log(non_static_private_member++);
};
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6550020/2249536) explains the reasoning behind such code generation a bit.

For private fields, you can do a trick similar to JS:

```
class Foo
   constructor: ->
       non_static_private_member = 10
       console.log(non_static_private_member++)
       @some = -> console.log(non_static_private_member)

a = new Foo  # output >> "10"
b = new Foo  # output >> "10"
a.some() # output >> "11"
console.log a.constructor.name # output >> "Foo"
```

Comment: I've already known the details why coffee will generate something like that. I just need some code that will output the value that I expected, and have a non-static private property that can be accessed in the object scope, and the constructor behaves right.

Comment: Why not move your `non_static_private_member = 10` into the constructor then? That would yield you same results as with your JS snippet.

Comment: I update my question, please see it. See the `a_public_method` part.

Answer (score 2):

> How do you translate the js code above to coffee?

You put all the code that resides in the constructor function `Foo` in the `constructor` of a `Foo` class:

```
class Foo
  # what you put here *is* static
  constructor: ->
    # it's an instance member, so it goes into the constructor
    non_static_private_member = 10;

    @a_public_method = ->
      non_static_private_member = 1
      return

    console.log(non_static_private_member++);

a = new Foo(); # output >> "10"
b = new Foo(); # output >> "10"
```

Comment: Write everything in the constructor. That's a bit crazy.

Comment: Well, that's what you did in your javascript function as well. Crazy or not.

Comment: Well, thanks. Since @YellowAfterlife updated his answer first, I'll accept his, and vote up yours.